# Cannot connect to Microsoft Access Database only when file is open using PHP?

Tags: php, database, ms-access, server, odbc

I am creating a Restful API for an android app using already available Microsoft Access database that is being used for other application(Visual basic Application) already. kind of two different applications on single database.

I am able to connect to database and perform query using code

```
 $conn = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

But when database is open my PHP files give this error -

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: 63 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0xee0 Thread 0xa20 DBC 0xa0c78cd8 Jet'.
```

Is there a work around to achieve this ??

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research and trying different languages, I finally found the problem.

Access creates an extra file when opened, which File is used to share database between users. So a user will need permission not only to read the file but also modify the file.

All in all just needed to change folder security settings to read/ write/ modify for all users. And it was done.